# SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016 upgrade using database attach method and impact of skipping SQL backup/restore step

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration

I am in process of upgrade SP2013 to SP2016 using database attach method. Source **Web Applns/Service Applns** databases are huge and it take too much time to backup and restore on destination SQL Server. This time will add up in total downtime for upgrade.

To reduce the upgrade downtime, What I am thinking is to skip backup/restore step. Instead of taking source backup and restore on destination, I will directly attach source database to destination Web Applns and Serice Applns.

Is this possible?
Are there any challenges doing this?
Issues I will face by doing this?

Comment: I think you will still need to upgrade the databases though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/overview-of-the-upgrade-process